# Summation of falling factorials

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, finite-differences

I just want to know if I should evaluate $\sum(t+1)^\underline{4}$ the way we evaluate $\sum{t^\underline{4}}$.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you specifying lower and upper bounds on the summation?

Comment: It would just require a change in the variable of summation.

Comment: Yes, there are limits: from $1$ to $n-1$.

Comment: Change of variable? In this case, it is the same as the way one evaluates $\sum{t^\underline{4}}$ then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just shift $t$:

$$\sum_{t=1}^{n-1}(t+1)^{\underline 4}=\sum_{t=2}^nt^{\underline 4}=\frac15\left((n+1)^{\underline5}-2^{\underline 5}\right)=\frac15(n+1)^{\underline 5}$$

In effect I’m substituting $s=t+1$, rewriting the summation in terms of $s$, and then renaming $s$ back to $t$.

Comment: Great! Thanks Brian M. Scott.

Comment: @YYG: You’re welcome!

Comment: I am now going to post my last question on this difference equations things for today. @Brian M. Scott.